# Parse NSString and replace certain substrings

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, replace, nsstring

Say I have a string that contains: "My computer is on fire! What should I do?" and I wanted to parse this string for all the substrings that had a length greater than 2. If the substring's length was greater than 2 I want to replace it with the word "boss".

How can I achieve this while still preserving punctuation and capitalization (ignore apostrophes)? Then return the new string with all the newly replaced words.

What I'm thinking as to how this would work would be something like:

```
NSString *original = @"My computer is on fire! What should I do?";
NSArray *stringArray = [original componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@" .,?!"]];

// Now compare this array to the original string
for (NSString *str in stringArray) {
   if ([original isEqualToString:str]) {
      // And this is where I start to have trouble
    }
}
```

Comment: What would you expect the output to be for your example?

Comment: What is your definition of "substring" here? Words?

Comment: I would like it to return "My boss in on boss! Boss boss I do?". @maddy yes I'm calling words the substrings in this example.

Comment: @user2175433 Try thinking about the problem algorithmically. Divide it into steps. Try something yourself. This is really trivial.

Comment: @Monolo Thanks I didn't find that when I searched for an asnwer.